How to stop raycasting from going through buttons in unity?
I have a script, it is used to detect if a province is being hovered over or clicked, and if it is clicked, it is selected, with the UI appearing over the screen. However, when I select a province and then try to click the build button in my UI, the ray goes through the button and deselects the province without clicking the button. (HALF FIXED SEE EDIT BELOW)
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ProvinceSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject actionPanel;
    public BuildStructure provinceBuilder;
    public float hoverBrightness = 1.5f;
    public float originalBrightness = 1.0f;

    private Material provinceMaterial;
    private bool isSelected = false;
    private static GameObject selectedProvince;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private int provinceLayerMask;

    void Start()
    {
        actionPanel.SetActive(false);
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Camera>();
        provinceMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        // Set the province layer mask to ignore raycasts
        provinceLayerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Provinces");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isSelected || IsHovering())
        {
            provinceMaterial.SetFloat("_Brightness", hoverBrightness);
        }
        else
        {
            provinceMaterial.SetFloat("_Brightness", originalBrightness);
        }

        if (isSelected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Check if the mouse is over UI
            if (!IsPointerOverButton())
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                // Perform a raycast only against the provinces layer mask
                if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, provinceLayerMask))
                {
                    DeselectProvince();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (selectedProvince != null && selectedProvince != gameObject)
        {
            selectedProvince.GetComponent<ProvinceSelection>().DeselectProvince();
        }

        // Perform a raycast to check for UI elements between the camera and the clicked point
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        bool hitUI = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, LayerMask.GetMask("UI"));

        // If a UI element is hit, return without selecting the province
        if (hitUI)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Proceed with province selection
        isSelected = true;
        selectedProvince = gameObject;
        Debug.Log("Clicked on province: " + gameObject.name);

        actionPanel.SetActive(true);
        Text provinceNameText = actionPanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        if (provinceNameText != null)
        {
            provinceNameText.text = gameObject.name;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No Text component found in the action panel.");
        }

        provinceBuilder.SetSelectedProvince(gameObject);
    }

    public void DeselectProvince()
    {
        isSelected = false;
        selectedProvince = null;
        actionPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    bool IsHovering()
    {
        if (mainCamera != null)
        {
            Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                return hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool IsPointerOverButton()
    {
        PointerEventData eventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        eventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        // Create a list of raycast results
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventData, results);

        // Check if any of the raycast results are UI buttons
        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            if (result.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

EDIT: I now have figured out how to stop the raycast from deselecting the provinces, but there is still another issue: When the camera is moved to see the map from a different angle, the buttons are moved so that provinces are underneath them, and when the button is pressed, the raycast goes through the button and selects the province underneath.

replace this code :
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class ProvinceSelection : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject actionPanel;
public BuildStructure provinceBuilder;
public float hoverBrightness = 1.5f;
public float originalBrightness = 1.0f;

private Material provinceMaterial;
private bool isSelected = false;
private static GameObject selectedProvince;
private Camera mainCamera;

void Start()
{
    actionPanel.SetActive(false);
    mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Camera>();
    provinceMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isSelected || IsHovering())
    {
        provinceMaterial.SetFloat("_Brightness", hoverBrightness);
    }
    else
    {
        provinceMaterial.SetFloat("_Brightness", originalBrightness);
    }

    if (isSelected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !IsPointerOverUIObject())
    {
        DeselectProvince();
    }
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (selectedProvince != null && selectedProvince != gameObject)
    {
        selectedProvince.GetComponent<ProvinceSelection>().DeselectProvince();
    }

    isSelected = true;
    selectedProvince = gameObject;
    Debug.Log("Clicked on province: " + gameObject.name);

    actionPanel.SetActive(true);
    Text provinceNameText = actionPanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    if (provinceNameText != null)
    {
        provinceNameText.text = gameObject.name;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No Text component found in the action panel.");
    }

    provinceBuilder.SetSelectedProvince(gameObject);
}

public void DeselectProvince()
{
    isSelected = false;
    selectedProvince = null;
    actionPanel.SetActive(false);
}

bool IsHovering()
{
    if (mainCamera != null)
    {
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            return hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool IsPointerOverUIObject()
{
    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
    return results.Count > 0;
}

}

Have you tried to exclude "UI" Layer on the raycast ? I suppose that all your UI is in UI layer (this is the layer by default when create Canvas or UI element)
if not the case, just change the layer on the top GameObject of your UI (canvas for example) to UI Layer.
Layer button explication
click on "yes, change children" to apply modification to all children
Apply to children image
edit your code is "update" function from this:
 RaycastHit hit;
 Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
 {
    DeselectProvince();
 }

to this:
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
int mask = ~(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI"));
if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10, mask))
{
    DeselectProvince();
}

10 is the maxDistance value, need to be provided to use the function's signature with "mask" parameter. Adjust this value with your use case.

Yes, I have tried to exlude the layer, did not work.

Figured it out, edited the on mouse down method so that if the mouse is clicked over a button ui gameobject, it does not follow through with the province selection part of the script.
Fix:
void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (IsMouseOverUIButton())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (selectedProvince != null && selectedProvince != gameObject)
    {
        selectedProvince.GetComponent<ProvinceSelection>().DeselectProvince();
    }

    isSelected = true;
    selectedProvince = gameObject;
    Debug.Log("Clicked on province: " + gameObject.name);

    actionPanel.SetActive(true);
    Text provinceNameText = actionPanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    if (provinceNameText != null)
    {
        provinceNameText.text = gameObject.name;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No Text component found in the action panel.");
    }

    provinceBuilder.SetSelectedProvince(gameObject);
}

